# Is there a Linux firewall that also limits applications access to specific ports?

Tags: networking, security, firewall

Is there a firewall application in Linux that lets you control network traffic on a per-application/per-process basis AND lets you limit that access by port/destination (like Outpost/Kerio/Sygate/Jetico or even the basic Windows Firewall does)?

For example, is there a firewall application that would allow a web browser to access https (port 443) only, and not other ports? How would this be achieved on Linux?

(The background to this question is that I am having a discussion with someone else, who wants to do this and is claiming there is no firewall app in Linux that provides equivalent functionality to these Windows applications they have been using. They are citing it as one of the main reasons why they don't want to switch to Linux.)

Comment: `iptables` (per-user restrictions) and SELinux / AppArmor (per-executable restrictions) offer this functionality. I don't know SELinux enough to understand how it provides a restriction on executable `/bin/webbrowser` but copes with `cp -p /bin/webbrowser /tmp/cheatsbrowser`, and so I can't give you a decent enough answer to be called an answer.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/219737/77217

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/16977/77217

Comment: And here's an SELinux example: https://serverfault.com/questions/366922/selinux-limit-httpd-outbound-connections-by-address-and-port

Comment: But the fundamental problem is that in order to make this work, the default has to be deny (otherwise you get the "`/tmp/cheatsbrowser`" problem). And then that's a lot of work to manage.